# aws bootstrap script not working for cli command setup

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

i have a simple script which i add as user data when launching an instance.
I'd like AWS CLI to be installed automatically on Red Hat

i use the following:

```
su ec2-user -l
cd ~
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user 
pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

nothing is being installed. This work from shell nicely.

Can somebody help how to install aws cli command for ec2-user as bootstrap script?

Answer (score 0):

add this to the first line

```
 #!/bin/bash
```